# Show selected option based on variable

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm a pretty novice programmer who is trying to implement something I thought would be pretty simple, but after searching haven't found a solution.

So right now I have an variable called **msg**. **msg** is dynamically generated and can be anywhere from 2-999.

I have a select that is very simple:

```
<form method='post' class='myForm' action=''>
   <select name='locationSelect' class='locationSelect' data-param='location_IDNUMBER'>
        <option value='1'>Exam Room</option>
        <option value='2'>Exam Room 2</option>
        <option value='3'>X-Ray Room</option>
        <option value='1000'>Check Out</option>
   </select>
</form>
```

My problem is: lets say **msg** has a value of **3**. How can I show the select with a value of 3, so the selected option(the option first visible before clicking the arrow) is X-Ray Room?

my code (taken out of a larger block of code is:

```
$e.find('.locationSelect').show();
```

How can I modify it to say something like:

```
$e.find('.locationSelect':value=msg).show(); //this would show the .locationSelect with the selected value being the one with the id of 3, or whatever msg is
```

Thanks for any and all help! If you need any more details, just ask!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try

```
$e.find('.locationSelect').val(msg);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/mowglisanu/ktcgy/

Comment: Woah. I was expecting it to be a lot more complicated, but this worked incredibly. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can use [$.fn.val(value)](http://api.jquery.com/val/#val2) to set the selected value of a dropdown.

Note that in case you pass to `$.fn.val` a value that is not present in the dropdown, the first option will be selected instead.